# ie.waitforvalue command doesn't work properly

Tags: g1ant

I tried to run this code but it doesn't work properly. It got stuck on line 3 and gives error "timeout, element not found".

```
ie.open g1ant.com
window ‴✱internet explorer✱‴
ie.waitforvalue script document.getElementsByClassName("footer_stuff").length expectedvalue 1
dialog ‴Page loaded!‴
ie.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because "footer_stuff" class doesn't exist in g1ant.com page. Did you mean "footer"? Try the following code instead.

```
ie.waitforvalue script document.getElementsByClassName("footer").length expectedvalue 1
```

[image]